# Display a single Observable, not an array

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I search around the web and no problem to find how display an `Observable<MyModel[]>`. But I don't find how display an `Observable<MyModel>` to a form.

I'd like display `firstName` value I tried this :

```
{{ myModel.firstName | async }}
```

and I'd like use it (bidirectional) in an  I tried this :

```
<input type="text" [(value)]="myModel.firstName">
```

I got this error :
*Cannot read property 'firstName ' of undefined at Object.eval [as updateRenderer]*

Thanks,

Comment: Use {{ myModel?.firstName | async }}

Answer (score 3):

Because you have to write it like this :

```
 {{ (myModel | async).firstName }}
```

With your syntax, Angular thinks that `firstName` is an observable, while it's a string.

Comment: are you sure can we use `async` pipe like this?

Comment: Pretty sure yes

Comment: Cool, I am not aware of this kind of usage of pipe +1

Comment: That's not really a pipe usage, you can also do it with variables like `(myModel as User).firstName`

Comment: About display in <input> ?

Comment: Well yes, isn't that what you asked ? I just answered your first line of code ...

Comment: Sorry I rephrase the question. I'd both in fact, you gave me 50% of the answer.

Comment: Then you can't do that. Well, actually, I don't know if you can, but you should not. You sure can display that value in a text or a label, but if you want to make changes to this value, **you should create a variable and change it instead of trying to change the observable**.

Answer (score 0):

you should use ngModel with input as

```
<input type="text" [ngModel]="myModel?.firstName">
```

or with interpolation as,

```
 {{ (myModel | async).firstName }}
```

Comment: That's strange the service does not hit the database. I log the URL and the service works fine. Strangely when I use the "interpolation" I hit the database but nothing in the input.